# How to fix the code in the values so that there are random numbers?

Tags: python, math, random, neural-network

I don’t know in programming, I need to fix the code, in the values of "M" and "L" I need to make random numbers consisting of 128 bits substituted?

```
def extended_gcd(aa, bb):
    lastremainder, remainder = abs(aa), abs(bb)
    x, lastx, y, lasty = 0, 1, 1, 0
    while remainder:
        lastremainder, (quotient, remainder) = remainder, divmod(lastremainder, remainder)
        x, lastx = lastx - quotient*x, x
        y, lasty = lasty - quotient*y, y
    return lastremainder, lastx * (-1 if aa < 0 else 1), lasty * (-1 if bb < 0 else 1)

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = extended_gcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise ValueError
    return x % m

M = 0x5FFDF9E967A054B02E0C56CDCF816A98
L = 0x45C42EF3369B5F069C57B4FF54F307F1

with open("results.txt", 'w') as f:
    print(hex(M*L), file=f)
```

Comment: why the neural-network tag ?! What have you tried so far ? show us some code/effort before asking for help. For now it just seems you want people to do the job for you.

Comment: @LoneWanderer I am not good at programming. I used this tag because many neural network programmers deeply study the topic of random numbers at a high level. I just need to fix this code so that this formula in the code generates numbers, sorting out new random numbers from the value "M" and "L". Could you help me? I would be grateful to you for any help!

Comment: Are you searching GCD for random 128 bit numbers ... what are you up to ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, all you'd have to do is:

```py
import random

with open("results.txt", "w") as f:
    for _ in range(num_of_rows):  # num_of_rows is the number of such results you want to store, replace it by the number
        M = random.randrange(16**32)
        L = random.randrange(16**32)
        print("0x{:066x}".format(M*L), file=f)
```

Comment: Please tell me how to make this function a generator and write a lot of data to the "results.txt" file.
At the moment, I get only one value. When I run the script, I need to get more random values.

Comment: @IziTors edited the answer let me know if this works for you

Comment: I get an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @IziTors if your program was working fine from the beginning, you should not be having this issue due to the above set of lines. What else did you change?

Comment: I use python 3 and put import random2
Now it looks like this: https://pastebin.com/eLMYtzV8
But still getting an error: print (hex (M * L), file = f)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @IziTors can you check the answer now?

Comment: Yes, thanks, everything is perfectly randomly generated and multiplied, but another complex problem arose.
This script does not put zeros at the beginning in values of 65 characters & 64 characters


0xfc7d8e9abed50a4d67ec1beb8ba9e159516e112437efe7a50a0292887a3c270 - 65 characters
0xbaf519697a749db796f42a17377c3abb69b8de2b1bd82e31c37e16e02fb6b9  - 64 characters
should be like this:
0x0fc7d8e9abed50a4d67ec1beb8ba9e159516e112437efe7a50a0292887a3c270 - 66 characters
All values must be 66 characters long. How to fix this please tell me?